# Auto-starting Twonky Server on Ubuntu 18.04 using systemd

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd

I was trying to set up a Twonky Server on Ubuntu. The server works fine, but I could not get `systemd` to autostart the server (using a service file I created at `/etc/systemd/system/twonkyserver.service`). Sometimes I got the cryptic error message that some `PID`-file (`/var/run/mediaserver.pid`) is not accessible, the exit code of the service is `13`, which apparently is a `EACCES Permission denied` error . The service runs as root.

I finally managed to fix the problem by setting `PIDFile` in the `twonkyserver.service` file to `/var/run/mediaserver.pid`. For reference, find the service file below:

```sh
[Unit]
Description=Twonky Server Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/twonky/twonky.sh start
ExecStop=/usr/local/twonky/twonky.sh stop
ExecReload=/usr/local/twonky/twonky.sh reload
ExecRestart=/usr/local/twonky/twonky.sh restart
PIDFile=/var/run/mediaserver.pid
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer and mark it as solved so the question appears as an answered question

Comment: Thanks. I will post an answer now. It appears that I had to earn 15 reputation points first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described above, the below service file auto-starts the Twonky Server on boot. Simply create it using `vim /etc/systemd/system/twonkyserver.service`. This assumses that you have installed the Twonky Server to `usr/local/twonky`. The shell-file `twonky.sh` already provides a nice interface to the service file (`twonky.sh start|stop|reload|restart`, also see `twonky.sh -h`).

```sh
[Unit]
Description=Twonky Server Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/local/twonky/twonky.sh start
ExecStop=/usr/local/twonky/twonky.sh stop
ExecReload=/usr/local/twonky/twonky.sh reload
ExecRestart=/usr/local/twonky/twonky.sh restart
PIDFile=/var/run/mediaserver.pid
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

I would slightly amend the start and stop commands from twonky.sh and put them directly into the twonky.service file for systemd:

```
[Unit]
Description=Twonky Server Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple

#Systemd will ensure RuntimeDirectory for the PID file is created under /var/run
RuntimeDirectory=twonky
PIDFile=/var/run/twonky/mediaserver.pid
# use the -mspid argument for twonkystarter to put the pid file in the right place
ExecStart=/usr/local/twonky/twonkystarter -mspid /var/run/twonky/mediaserver.pid -inifile /usr/local/twonky/twonkyserver.ini -logfile /usr/local/twonky/twonky.log -appdata /usr/local/twonky
ExecStop=kill -s TERM $MAINPID
ExecStopPost=-killall -s TERM twonkystarter
ExecStopPost=-killall -s TERM twonky
# Twonky 8.5.1 doesn't reload, it stops instead (on arm at least)
# ExecReload=kill -s HUP $MAINPID 

Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

You need to be sure the paths in the ExecStart command match where you unpacked twonky, and also where you want the .pid file, configuration, logfile and runtime appdataunless you are happy with their default locations.

After putting that all into/etc/systemd/system/twonky.server, run

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start twonky
sudo systemctl enable twonky
```